# VSTS How to make a Release be triggered automatically upon successful Build completion?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I often do the following, through VSTS web UI:

1. Queue a build. Wait for it to finish.
2. If the build finished successfully, release it.

I want for step 2 to trigger automatically upon step 1 completion, so I won't have to babysit it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your release definition:

In the old editor:

- On the *Artifacts* tab, link the build as an artifact source
- On the *Triggers* tab, turn on **Continuous Deployment**.

In the new editor:

- On the pipelines tab, click the **+** button to add an artifact source.
- Click the lightning bolt icon next to the artifact and set the **Continuous Deployment** trigger to *enabled*.

That will create a release. For any environments upon which you want to immediately start deployment, make sure the pipeline is configured so that they start after the release is created.

For the record, this is [extremely well-documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers).